# getting data posted by ajax into php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I am updating this question for clarity. I am using jquery sortable together with AJAX (see code below) to to sort and save an images grid. All works fine and I get the following success message - both in my script and on the firebug network console.

```
            //firebug params and success message output
             item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10

            //request header
                Host: example.com
                User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
                Accept: */*
                Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
                Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                Referer: http://example.com/PropertyIndex/property_gallery/draggable.php
                Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
                X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
                Content-Length: 90
                Cookie: PHPSESSID=b1lr9he4l2hbcnlkcsebfq2134
                Connection: keep-alive
 //request body
 item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=2&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10
```

So it appears the data is being posted successfully. However after hours of searching I cannot work out how to return the posted data -- item[] array ---to PHP so that it can be processed by the FOREACH Loop also shown in my code below: Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

```
            filename: draggable.php

                <!doctype html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                  <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Display as grid</title>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
                  <style>
                  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
                  #sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
                  </style>
                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                  <script>
                  $( function() {
                    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
                    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
                  } );
                  </script>
                </head>
                <body>

                <?php
                <!-----------get media_urls from database----------------->

                 <div id="element">
                <ul id="sortable">


                <li id="item-1" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url1 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-2" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url1 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-3" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url2 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-4" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url3 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-5" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url4 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-6" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url5 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-7" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url6 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-8" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url7 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-9" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url8 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>
                <li id="item-10" class="ui-state-default">     <img class="image" src="<?php echo $media_url9 ?>" width="100px" height="100px">       </li>


                </ul>
                //test results
                Query string: <span></span>
                <p class ="result"></p>

                </div>

                //post the data using ahax
                <script>

                $('ul').sortable({

                    update: function (event, ui) {
                        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

                         $('span').text(data);      //test success 2

                        $.ajax({
                            data: data,
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'draggable.php',
                            success:function(result){
                            $(".result").html(data);}
                        });  

                    }
                });

                //$(window).resize(resize);

                </script>

                <?php

                print_r()//an empty array--but why?

                $i = 0;

                //this loop is failing to echo the success result ie item[]
                foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {
                    echo "each".$value;
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>

                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: php and javascript are not directly connected. you cannot use javascript to modify the php since the php has executed long before your run-time javascript's user input has been selected. your ajax call would have to write the results back to the div with the new values (hope that makes sense.  i think that you need your failed piece of code to be in your draggable.php file

Comment: Where are your posted results saved to - database, session, file?

Comment: thanks happy. Help me out a little more would you please? I am not sure quite what I should do to implement your solution. I have added a little bit more info on  the request header data in my question. I suspect I am missing the obvious here

Comment: at the moment Jeff the posted results are not being saved. That is what I am trying to achieve by adding an update database routine to the foreach loop. But right now I cant see the echo'ed $values of the $_POST['item'] array in the foreach loop so I haven't gone as far as trying to update the database. Once I see the echo'ed values I will add the database update sql to the foreach loop

Comment: Happy--I think I get what you mean on reflection. My ajax url is posting the to the same page as the ajax routine ie daraggable.php. So should I do the ajax post to a new page eg draggable_posted_data.php and then put the foreach loop on that new page script so that the PHP executes after the ajax post?

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. with $.post it's working. I would also recommend to process the data of the new sequence in another php-file.

```
$.post("draggable-processing.php",{
   data:data
},
function(data){
   $(".result").html(data);
});
```

data is not an object but a string that You have to explode by hand:

```
// file draggable-processing.php:
<? 
$aSequence = explode('&',$_POST['data']);
for($i = 0; $i<count($aSequence);$i++){
    preg_match('/=([a-z0-9]*)$/', $aSequence[$i], $treffer);
    echo($treffer[1]."\n");
}
```